# rightBarButtonItem image not showing up

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbaritem

Can anyone help me out understand what is wrong in my code . I am not getting it my code compiles fine without any errors but my image is not showing up.I am sure my image is present in **Assests** folder and I am giving the correct name of my images as well. I am doing it programatically. Below is my code-:

***AppDelegate-:**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        windowLayout()
        application.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        return true
    }

    func windowLayout()
    {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeController(collectionViewLayout: layout))
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 238/255, green: 32/255, blue: 31/255, alpha: 1)
        let statusBarView = UIView()
        statusBarView.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 194/255, green: 31/255, blue: 31/255, alpha: 1)
        window?.addSubview(statusBarView)
        window?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        //window?.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: statusBarView)
        //window?.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0(20)]", views: statusBarView)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
        //UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(),forBarMatrics: .default)
    }
```

**Extension File-:**

```
import UIKit


protocol navigationBarItems {
    func searchBarButton()
    func handleMoreButton()
}


extension UINavigationController:navigationBarItems
{
    func handleMoreButton() {

    }

    func searchBarButton()
    {
        let searchBarImage = UIImage(named: "search-icon")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
        let searchImage = UIBarButtonItem(image: searchBarImage, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(handleSearch))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchImage

    }

    func handleSearch()
    {
        print("123")
    }

}
```

**Controller class-:**

```
class HomeController: UICollectionViewController,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpLayout()
        setUpMenuBar()
        fetchJsonData()
        navigationController?.searchBarButton()
    }
```

I have tested by putting up a breakpoint to check my function is getting called or not . And it is working fine but image not showing up please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make extension of UIViewController instead of UINavigationController

```
extension UIViewController:navigationBarItems
{
    func handleMoreButton() {

    }

    func searchBarButton()
    {
        let searchBarImage = UIImage(named: "search-icon")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
        let searchImage = UIBarButtonItem(image: searchBarImage, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(handleSearch))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchImage

    }

    func handleSearch()
    {
        print("123")
    }

}
```

Now call this method from `viewDidLoad``

```
class HomeController: UICollectionViewController,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpLayout()
        setUpMenuBar()
        fetchJsonData()
        self.searchBarButton()
    }
```

Comment: @Nirva D Thanks it worked . But why extension UINavigationController was not working?